# How do I install an Edimax EW-7811Un wireless adapter?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 to my old computer (a Dell) after XP began to run very slow, and am now trying to install a Edimax EW-7811Un 150 Mbps Wireless 11n Nano Size USB Adapter to connect to my Wifi.  When I put the driver disk in, an error message comes up saying it cannot find the autorun program.  I am new to using this OS and am entirely lost.  How can I get the driver installed?  Thanks!

Comment: Does the driver disk contain linux or windows drivers?

Comment: It contains linux and windows.  I had one that didn't support linux so i specifically bought this one hoping it would work.

Comment: That one *should* work on Ubuntu without installing anything (Realtek chipset). Are you having problems getting wireless to work?

Comment: Joe, you should add the usual output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` to the question. I wouldn't bother with the driver CD, because even if there is a Linux driver, it's probably outdated. That particular device actually has the built in driver, but [it doesn't work](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/852190). You'll, most likely, need to install the river from realtek.com, and for that, we'll need the chipset, or in other words, the output I've asked for.

Comment: How do I find the output?

Comment: Run the command `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` in the terminal, then copy-paste the output to a text file or this question (if you have internet, otherwise use the put-to-text-file method, then take that file to an internet-enabled system, and copy-paste its contents into your question with the "edit" button)

Comment: > 04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard [1458:e000]
 Kernel driver in use: r8169